# Using Sinatra and jQuery without redirecting on POST

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I am trying to use jQuery to submit a form to my Sinatra app, but when POSTing via the AJAX, the Sinatra app is displaying a blank page. I would like it to stay on the same page, and update the content I have specified in the javascript. Here is my code, stripped down:

```
post '/register' do
  register( params )
end
get '/register' do
  haml :register
end
```

And here is my javascript in the haml file:

```
:javascript
        $(function() {
                $("button#submit").click(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "/register",
                                data: $('form.register').serialize(),
                                success: function(){
                                        $("#message").html("Successfully registered")
                                },
                                error: function(){
                                        $("#message").html("Not Successful")
                                }
                        });
                });
        });
```

Comment: What's your rendered HTML?

Comment: No Ajax call does not redirect page. Did you set the button type to be submit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function() {
  $("form#the_id").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/register",
      data: $('form.register').serialize(),
      success: function(){
        $("#message").html("Successfully registered")
      },
      error: function(){
        $("#message").html("Not Successful")
      }
    });
  });
});
```

`$("form#the_id").submit(...` detects the form submission. `e.preventDefault();` prevents the form submission. The rest submits an Ajax request.

Don't forget to change `#the_id` to your form id.