# Sinatra: Present Form input without redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, sinatra

I am trying to make a website, where a user can input some data. I would then run a number of methods on this data using sinatra and then display the results on the same input page (i.e. without refreshing (or redirecting) the page - as such the input data is still the form).

I understand that I would probably have to use javascript to watch the submit button and use that to stop the redirection.

I know ruby quit well, but do not know javascript that well; so please bear with me.

I have done quite a bit of research on this, but I haven't got anything to work. (This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377367/using-sinatra-and-jquery-without-redirecting-on-post) is similar, but I haven't even been able to successfully use that).

This is the my sinatra file. Currently, pressing the submit button redirects to an another page.

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    erb :search
end

post '/' do
    @the_input = "<h2>ID header</h2>#{params[:input]}"
end

__END__

@@ search
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>   
    <body>

        <form action="/#result" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="input">
          <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <div class="result" id="result" style="display: none;">
            <div class="content">
            <!-- this is where the Results should display... -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#result').submit(function(){
                //parse AJAX URL
                var action = $(this).attr('action');
                var index  = action.indexOf('#');
                var url    = action.slice(0, index);
                var hash   = action.slice(index, action.length);

                $('.result').show();
                $('.result .content').html(index);
            })
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would really be grateful if someone could help me to get this to work so that the input of the form is displayed into the `content` div. Any explanation of what you are doing would also be extremely helpful.

Many Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This may help you](https://ididitmyway.herokuapp.com/past/2011/2/27/ajax_in_sinatra/)

Basically prevent default redirecting.